# Sum of Squares/Square of Sum Difference

Tags: python, programming-challenge

I am doing Project Euler problem #6. This is the **question** it asks:

> The sum of the squares of the first ten natural numbers is,
>
> $$1^2 + 2^2 + \ldots + 10^2 = 385$$
>
> The square of the sum of the first ten natural numbers is,
>
> $$(1 + 2 + \ldots + 10)^2 = 55^2 = 3025$$
>
> Hence the difference between the sum of the squares of the first ten natural numbers and the square of the sum is 3025 − 385 = 2640.
>
> Find the difference between the sum of the squares of the first one hundred natural numbers and the square of the sum.

My implementation in Python is as follows:

```
def sum_of_squares(n):
    return sum([i**2 for i in range(1, n+1)])

def square_of_sum(n):
    return sum(range(1, n+1)) ** 2

print square_of_sum(100) - sum_of_squares(100)
```

It works but I was wondering if my implementation is good and fast enough?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Implementation is good indeed, but I have some reservations calling it fast. Its complexity is **O(n)**. As usual (including, but not limited to, Project Euler), an ultimate optimizer is math. Recall that

> $$ 1 + 2 + \ldots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

and

> $$ 1^2 + 2^2 + \ldots + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

so the result

> $$ \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} - \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \frac{(n-1)n(n+1)(3n+2)}{12}$$

can be achieved in **O(1)** time.

Comment: Btw. this *might* be a spoiler for a different Euler problem. I've often seen same problems with increased difficulty on the site.

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation looks fine.  This calculation is so trivial for a computer to do that it's not worth spending much time optimizing the implementation.

That said, the fact that you called `print` without parentheses indicates that you are using Python 2.  In Python 2, [`xrange()` would be slightly preferable to `range()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135041/1157100).

Alternatively, keep using `range()`, and [call `print()` with parentheses](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) to make your program compatible with Python 3.

Comment: Or use a `from __future__ import print_function`.

Answer (score 3):

One minor tweak I would suggest to your current implementation:

```
def sum_of_squares(n):
    return sum([i**2 for i in range(1, n+1)])
```

You don't need to built the list; `sum` will take the bare generator expression as an argument:

```
def sum_of_squares(n):
    return sum(i**2 for i in range(1, n+1)) # or xrange in 2.x
```

This will be quicker and also uses less memory (see e.g. [here](http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2008/09/05/speed-up-python-without-effort-using-generator-expressions/)).